# Interpretation of Carbon-13 NMR Spectra for Chemically Similar Carbon Atoms

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

I am analyzing the Carbon-13 NMR data from a reaction I will be modifying. There is not NMR data available for the specific compound I am attempting to synthesize; however, the compound I am synthesizeing only differs by the number of carbon atoms on the acyl group (from a Friedel-Crafts acylation). The compounds I will be synthesizing and analysing are **1-(5,7-dimethoxy-2,2-dimethyl-2H-1-benzopyran-8-yl)butanone (1)** and **1-(5,7-dimethoxy-2,2-dimethyl-2H-1-benzopyran-6-yl)butanone (2)** respectively. The compounds synthesized in the protocol I am following were **1-(5,7-dimethoxy-2,2-dimethyl-2H-1-benzopyran-8-yl)ethanone (4a)** and **1-(5,7-dimethoxy-2,2-dimethyl-2H-1-benzopyran-6-yl)ethanone (4b)** respectively. I will include images below. 14 peaks are expected from each of the carbon-13 NMR spectra since each carbon is chemically different; however, compound 4 only showed 13 NMR peaks. My hypothesis was that this was due to the fact the the methoxy carbons are so chemically similar that they appear as a single peak; however, I am not sure if this is the case. I expect that I can use this to my advantage in distinguishing compounds 1 and 2 when I synthesize them. The doi to the article is: 10.1016/j.bmc.2018.05.016. I will also include the NMR data below:

[image]

Comment: I apologize for the terrible quality image. I cannot figure out how to increase the resolution. The carbon-13 NMR data is also included in the paper if you cannot make this out.

Comment: I did not expect it just by looking at the molecules, but apparently (via software simulation, both by nmrdb.org and mnova) the methoxyl carbons have very close shift in 4b (they are 55.8 and 63.05 ppm in a4 and they collapse in 56.2 ppm in 4b)
Probably higher resolution 13C NMR, and for sure a HETCOR experiment (as the proton shifts are clearly non-degenerate), will distinguish them

Comment: I did not know there was a website that allowed you to calculate the theoretical NMR spectrum. Thanks for pointing that out! Unfortunately, I only have access to a 300 MHz spectrometer, so I will probably just use the fact that these peaks collapse on each other to distinguish my two compounds, as the proton NMR spectra of both of these compounds are highly similar.

Comment: Yes, generally all the NMR prediction methods are not very accurate in every case, so use them carefully, but they can give some insights, and on sets of "typical" and lucky molecules like this, they can give satisfactory results (mnova gave a very good prediction).